# To tilde or not to tilde

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

When writing batch `FOR` loops I've picked up a habit of using `tildes` in the variable placeholder names in the command portion of the script and enclose that with double quotes.

> **Example Syntax**
>
> ```
> FOR %%A IN ("*.*") DO ECHO "%%~A"
> ```

[image]

### Reason

I usually write scripts like this as a standard whether or not they are truly needed without thought. I like how it strips the double quotes from the `set` portion of the loop and then adds them back explicitly in the `command parameter` portion of the loop.

### Question

- Could there be a scenario where using the tilde could actually be harmful when used with a `FOR` loop via batch script or command line?
- What are some reasons from others experience or perhaps officially documented somewhere why you would or would not want to use `tildes` for this reason with `FOR` loops via cmd or batch?

Comment: I’ve never used them, never needed to. I wouldn’t, since I don’t want to glance at them and think they have anything to do with the user’s home folder. Stylistic choice, curious to see what others say.

Comment: Generally I don’t like to add little “tiddlybits” to commands just for shiggles.

Answer (score 3):

In your exact use case it doesn't make a difference but also doesn't harm :

- as file names iterated by a wildcard are always returned unquoted.

When iterating some double quoted strings (especially cmd line args `%*`)
I'd always use them:

```
@Echo off
For %%A IN (
    "this is a sentence"
    two words
    "some words"
) Do (
    Echo with tilde: "%%~A"
    Echo w/o  tilde: "%%A"
    Echo:
)
```

---

```
> SU1397704.cmd
with tilde: "this is a sentence"
w/o  tilde: ""this is a sentence""

with tilde: "two"
w/o  tilde: "two"

with tilde: "words"
w/o  tilde: "words"

with tilde: "some words"
w/o  tilde: ""some words""
```

Comment: Yes, that's the reason I use them based on habit because I was hit by that with the iteration of values having spaces!!